# SSL certificate for intranet web servers

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm interested to purchase a wild card SSL certificate for my public domain (say example.com), so that we can run intranet web servers using a universally recognized CA (e.g., GoDaddy). I do plan to publish the DNS names publicly (e.g. internal.example.com), but their IP addresses are actually LAN addresses (e.g., 192.*.*.*). We want to use public DNS, because these web servers may actually be development laptops which travel around, and thus we will use Dynamic DNS to update. It's our intention that these web servers will only be available on the LAN each one is currently running on.

Will that work universally with all clients, e.g., TLS v1.2 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the clients can route their traffic to these IP addresses, it will work (otherwise you won't get the connection, of course).

Certificate verification relies on two points:

- Verifying that the certificate is genuine, trusted and valid in time.
- Verifying that the identity of the certificate matches what you were looking for (host name verification).

This does not depend on how the DNS resolution mechanism. These mechanisms are also orthogonal to the SSL/TLS specifications (although they do recommend to verify the remote party's identity).

I've seen this sort of setup used on various clients and platforms (IE, Chrome, FF, Java clients on Windows/Linux/Mac) and it worked fine.

Of course, whether *all* implementations do this well is hard to guarantee. There might be some implementation that thinks it's a good idea to perform a reverse DNS lookup, for example.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. Your answer seems logical and was my original hope. I just wasn't sure, because it seems from cursory reading of tech news that recent TLS implementations are getting stricter.

(In fact, we were using self-signed certificates on our development servers, and had a special debug mode in our iOS app (i.e., the client) which would automatically trust the SSL certificate. But iOS 7 has made their TLS implementation stricter, and we can't find a way to make it trust our certificates.)

I'm planning to move forward with implementation and to follow up on this thread with the results.

Comment: I just verified that it does indeed work. I tried it on OX 10.8.5 Chrome 30 and iOS 7 UIWebView.